# Unique Union Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

Given a the set $a = \{1,...,n\}$ and let $b$ denote a set of subsets of $a$.

Find a subset of $c$ of $b$ so that the union of all subsets in $c$ is equal to $a$ and the intersection of any of the subsets of $c$ is empty.

How is this problem called in literature, i tried unique union, but thats not right.

Comment: $c$ is called a partition of $a$. Just finding a partition is easy, $\{a\}$ is a partition. You probably want to give more constraints about this partition.

Comment: i found it it is called unqiue set cover

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is a partition under the extra condition that the elements of $c$ are not empty.

Comment: no its called exact cover problem

Comment: @drhab: Yeah, you're right. I implicitly assumed we're not interested in trivialities. :-)

Comment: OK, so it's called an [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) or a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).  It's settled now?

Comment: yes exact cover was what i was looking for!